# Counting the number of ways to recursively add up to a number N without permutations

Tags: c++, recursion

For an assignment I have to write two recursive functions that take a number `N` and return the number of ways there are to add up to that number.

The first function allows permutations, for example: `countWithPerms(3)` would count   `1 + 2` and `2 + 1` as two different solutions, while `countIgnorePerms(3)` would count them as the same solution.

I wrote the `countIgnorePerms()` method:

```
int countWithPerms(int number, int amountLeft)
{

    if(amountLeft == 1)
        return 0;
    else
        amountLeft--;

    return (countWithPerms(number, amountLeft) + 1) + 
           (countWithPerms(amountLeft, amountLeft));

}//end countWithPerms()
```

The first call to this method will have the same number passed to it twice, all subsequent method calls will find the number of sums of `(n-1)` and add that to the sums of `N`.

What I am having trouble figuring out is how to modify this method so that it does not accept any permutations. I am not quite sure where to even begin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem?  Are you allowed to add up any integers to the target, or just 1 and 2?

Comment: "return (countWithPerms(number, amountLeft)..." if `countWithPerms` is ever called with `amountLeft != 1`, you have an infinite recursion. From the text, however, it seems that method should be `countIgnorePerms`. Fix a typo?

Comment: Is zero included, i.e. 0 + 3 in your example?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: It is easy if it is, the answer is infinity [3, 0 + 3, 0 + 0 + 3,...]

Comment: `countIgnorePerms` just counts the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)). You can find some hints on that page.

Comment: @amit: Depends if he's just looking for two-operand expressions or allowing more.  That is, for 3 does he want: 1 + 2, 2 + 1, or does he want 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 2, 2 + 1

Comment: @D1990c: is your problem writing countIgnorePerms or countWithPerms?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is using a `std::set` to contain the possible solutions, but this approach will consume quite a bit of memory.

You can create a class that holds a possible solution `[1,2]` for example.

The class will contain these values sorted.

overload the `operator<` for these class.

Create a `set` [initialized as empty] and pass it [by reference] through the reucrsion. Each time you find a possible solution - add it to the set.

Since the `set` does not contain duplicates, at the end - number of possibilities is `set.size()`

Comment: That doesn't scale, the number of partitions grows fast.

Comment: @DanielFischer: true, this why I mentioned it consumes a lot of memory. But since it is homework - I don't assume it is going to be invoked with large input, since the calculation time itself grows exponentially as well.

Comment: The calculation time doesn't need to grow exponentially, you can calculate e.g. `p(200)` in a few seconds even without using Euler's recursion. I guess the teacher is after such an implementation.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It actually depends at which part of his studies the OP is... Given the solution of the `withPermutations()` the OP provided, it seems to me they are just learning recursion and basic c++ concepts.. Though I could be wrong, of course

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you created your lists in non-descending order (to allow for duplicates); then you would have a unique solution for each possible set of integers that can form a solution.

So for your N=3 example, you would produce 1+1+1 and 1+2 and 3 as the only solutions.